# C#: need a blocking FIFO queue similar to Java's LinkedBlockingQueue

Tags: c#, multithreading, queue, blocking, fifo

need something similiar with java's `LinkedBlockingQueue`.

method of interest: `messageQueue.poll(120000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);`
meaning ..try to get item..and if in X unit of time you still have no item..return null

that + i must be **FIFO**

after some googling (but havent yet tested): i found ConcurrentQueue (has FIFO behaviour), BlockingCollection (FiFO OR no FIFO??)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`BlockingCollection` can be used with any number of different types of collections.  If you don't manually pass in a specific type of concurrent collection it will uses a `ConcurrentQueue`, meaning it will do exactly what you want.  You can uses a concurrent stack type, or a concurrent priority queue if you want, which is why it uses a general name such as Blocking Collection, and not BlockingConcurrentQueue.

All of this is listed on the MSDN page for `BlockingCollection` if you don't want to take my word for it.